# Modifying an object using a remote method

Tags: ruby, scope

I am trying to take an object and then modify it within a method another object, but it is not returning the updated value.  This is best explained by an example:

```
@testobject = "This is a string."
handler=Handler.new
handler.load(@testobject)
puts @testobject
=> "This is a string."
```

handler.load:

```
def load(@testobject)
  @testobject = @testobject + " Modified!"
end
```

I'm sure this has to do with the scope of the object, but I am stumped as to how to make the original object accessible and modifiable by other classes.

**Edit**: This is a bad example, perhaps.  I am using a string to help me understand how the variables/object scope works, but in my actual program, it is not a string.

To be more specific, I have an object ("stream") that I am using.  Then I have a "handler" object that is like a plugin, each of which needs to modify the first "stream" object.  For each handler, I want to call handler.load, have it run the appropriate methods to change the settings on the "stream" object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify your objects only by their methods. For strings it may be `replace` or `gsub`. For arrays it may be `<<` method, for example.

in scope of handler

```
@testobject = @testobject + " Modified!"
```

means "assign `@testobject + " Modified!` to instance variable of instance of Handler `@testobject`", it doesn't modifies @testobject.

By the way, which version of ruby do you use? ruby 1.9.3 cannot interpret

```
def load(@testobject)
  @testobject = @testobject + " Modified!"
end
```

because there is no way to declare method with instance variable as argument.

Comment: Perfect.  The fact that an object can only be modified by their methods helped me with this immensely.  Thanks!

Comment: `+` _is_ a [method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-2B) from @testobject, it just results in a new object and does not modify @testobject. The `<<`method would change @testobject.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you put `@testobject` as the parameter name.

When this line is executed :

```
@testobject = @testobject + " Modified!"
```

The real parameter name is shadowed by the instance variable.

However, even if you removed the @, you would only affect the local copy of your variable.

You can use `String#replace` to effectively update the string.

Try that :

```
def load(testobject)
  testobject.replace(testobject + " Modified!")
end
```

Comment: I've edited my question to be more specific, I am not actually using a string, just using it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` method results in a new string; the @testobject variable keeps referring to the old one.

```
def load(@testobject)
  @testobject = @testobject << " Modified!"
end
```

`<<` is a mutating method, it does modify the object the @testobject variable refers to.

Answer (score -1):

```
@testobject = 'This is a string.'
callback = Proc.new {|suffix| @testobject = @testobject + suffix}
handler.load(callback)

def load(callback)
    callback.call(' Modified!')
end
```